# PCI expansion card - for SATA III

Tags: pci

I need some advice and help on how can I add SATA III hard drives to my old pc. Following is the PC specs

Mobo: ASUS KV8-X
CPU: AMD Athlon 64 3200+ 2.2 Ghz
OS: Windows 7 Pro 32 bit

The machine has a 80 GB hard drive on which OS is installed. I want to add two 3TB Seagate SATAIII hard drives. The model of Seagate drives is ST3000DM001. I have tried installing/connecting the drives to mobo connectors but they are not detected either in BIOS or windows. After a lot of searching through web and reading forums, I tried updating bios with latest firmware, reinstalled OS, installed VIA drivers etc but I could not get the drives detected in the BIOS. I am now considering using a PCI to SATA III card with 2 ports to connect these drives. I could not find any PCI card with SATA III connectors (all most all of them are PCIe). I don't really understand the differences and was hoping someone could help me identify a card or other options to add these drives. The machine is just used for sharing media and backup, I am not too fussed about the performance. Also I don't really want to spend too much as well. I am thinking if I can get a card in about $30 that would be good. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

You aren't likely to find a PCI to Sata III card because the maximum bandwidth of Sata III isn't supported by PCI (~750MBps vs ~133MBps). Sata III drives should work on Sata II or Sata I buses, so there's probably another reason why your drives aren't being detected that has something to do with software or firmware.

Also, have you checked to see that the drives are plugged into the power supply? If they are, are they spinning? There's always the chance that the 12V rail is being over-tasked (it should support at least 4 Amps your case, since hard drives generally consume ~20 Watts).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will check it but do you think the drives should work on my mobo (as secondary storage drives).